# PHP - Improve random number sequence generation

Tags: php, random, numbers

I guess here comes my first question on SO.

I'm currently working on a website and I have to generate 6 numbers between 1 and 29 (one of each max) for a lottery. As they can be in any order, I simply sort them afterwards.

If I'm not mistaken, it should mean that there's `(29*28*27*26*25*24) / 6! = 475020` different possible combinations.

I've tried different ways of genereting the sequences, either using mt_rand or random_int (from [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat)) but when I test it with something like 10k iterations, I always get around 100 duplicates, even though they are like 465k combinations still available.

Here are the code samples I've been trying :

```
// Using an array and mt_rand (or random_int, giving same results)
// Also tried shuffling the array instead of simply reindexing it, not better

$values = range(1, 29);

while(count($values) > 6) {
    unset($values[mt_rand(0, count($values) - 1)]);
    $values = array_values($values);
}



// Creating the array from random numbers (same results using random_int)

$values = array();
while (count($values) < 6) {
    $r = mt_rand(1, 29);
    if (in_array($r, $values)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $values[] = $r;
    }
}
```

So well... My questions are :

- Is there a way to improve what I'm currently doing ?
- Is that the way it's gonna be and I have to deal with it ?
- Am I simply doing it wrong ?

Thanks !

Lyn.

*PS : Looked through many questions, but didn't find anything filling my needs, sorry if I didn't look well enough !*

**Just to make a few things clear:** Using random_int (which makes use of /dev/urandom or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) doesn't improve anything, which I thought would. And I don't want to use any external API (like random.org) if possible.

Comment: `$numbers = range(1,29); shuffle($range); $draw = array_slice($range, 0, 6); echo implode(',' $draw);`.... and you'll never get any duplicates in any given draw

Comment: @MarkBaker The parameters of the implode method are in the wrong order.

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not getting duplicates in a specific draw, I'm getting duplicate draws. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough :)

Comment: @MeneerVenus Nah, they are in the right order, but it's missing the comma. The other order of arguments is accepted but not recommended : http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: @Lynesth Oh I thought it was causing a fatal error, turns out there is a comma missing and the `$numbers` variable was supposed to be called `$range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using random_int (which makes use of /dev/urandom or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) doesn't improve anything, which I thought would.

Sure it does, it's just not something you can identify visually. `mt_rand()` and `rand()` only allow about 2<sup>32</sup> possible seeds and 2<sup>32</sup> possible outputs and, most importantly, have **deterministic sequences**: [if you know a few outputs, you can predict the rest until it's reseeded](http://www.openwall.com/php_mt_seed).

Your operating system's CSPRNG doesn't have any such limits. Knowing a handful of `random_int()` outputs (which in PHP are limited to 2<sup>32</sup> possible values on 32-bit systems, 2<sup>64</sup> on 64-bit systems) will not give you any information on future outputs.

> I'm currently working on a website and I have to generate 6 numbers between 1 and 29 (one of each max) for a lottery. As they can be in any order, I simply sort them afterwards.

Okay, that's a neat idea. You definitely want a CSPRNG here.

> when I test it with something like 10k iterations, I always get around 100 duplicates, even though they are like 465k combinations still available.

As others have pointed out, this is the [birthday problem/paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) at play.

If you need a solution, try something like this:

```
function random_unique_select($num, array $possible_values)
{
    $sizeof = count($possible_values);
    if ($num > $sizeof) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$num is too large');
    }
    $selected = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; ++$i) {
        // Grab a random int [0, ... N - 1]
        $r = random_int(0, $sizeof - 1);
        // Copy the selected value into $selected
        $selected[] = $possible_values[$r];
        // Delete it from the range of possible values
        unset($possible_values[$r]);
        // N has grown smaller by 1
        --$sizeof;
        // Reset keys; we want this to be zero-indexed.
        $possible_values = array_values($possible_values);
    }
    return $selected;
}

$lottery = random_unique_select(6, range(1,29));
```

Demos:

- http://3v4l.org/Hb97A (single-pass; uses`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`)
- http://3v4l.org/E7cb5 (100,000 iterations -> very small numbers of duplicates)

Comment: The code sample you provided doesn't change much. I also tried generated 10k sequences using random.org and I'm getting even more duplicates than using my methods so I guess it's ok. Selecting your answer because it's the one I prefer, but thanks to everyone answering !

Answer (score 1):

Read about the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

According to my calculations ([bc calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language))), the probability of getting a duplicate combination with 6 out of 29 items is 50% or better with 812 number of sequences.

```
define p(n, k) { return (n-k)/n; }
n=475020
m=1; for (k=0; k<811; k++) m *= p(n, k); m
.500649663424
m=1; for (k=0; k<812; k++) m *= p(n, k); m
.499794905988
```

Comment: The probabilty of getting a duplicate with 10,000 sequences is approx 99.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990751%

Comment: So I guess that it means I'm doing it well enough already ? Why can't I see any difference between mt_rand and some other "better" way of doing it (/dev/urandom for example) ?

Comment: And is there a way to calculate "How many duplicates should I expect when casting X sequences ?" ? Cause the probability of getting a duplicate increases each time I don't get one and simply stays the same when I get one ? Or am I overthinking everything and I should just go on with what I've got ?

Comment: If you want to guarantee no repetition, put all the (`475,020`) values in an array, shuffle the array and select the first `N` (`10,000`).

Answer (score 0):

To improve "randomness", you could try cryptographic libraries, e.g. [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

There is a random() function in their math-library [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/math.html#math_biginteger_random).

EDIT: Numbers generated by computers can't be *random*. The best *pseudo-random* results you can get with cryptographic libraries, the simplest, most random solution is the one of @Matthias Leuffen.

Answer (score 0):

rand() and mt_rand() rely on pure mathematics to produce pseudo-random numbers.

To get real random numbers you could use the webservice of http://www.random.org

Comment: That's the simplest and most random solution, but you are dependent on an API. Numbers generated by computers can't be *random*, just pseudo-random.

Comment: I know about random.org, but as @user3469305 just said, I don't want to rely on external API to do it. Want I don't really understand is that I am getting the same results using mt_rand or random_int (if you take a look at the implementation, it uses /dev/urandom, which is available on the server).

Answer (score -1):

You could, assuming the correct extensions are installed, make use of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

Example:

```
function strong_random() {
    return hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20)));
}
```

Note: due to the implementation of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`, this function will be **very slow**.

Quick and dirty, of course, could use adding a max length parameter.

Comment: Your function isn't correct, you should pass a variable, not a bool as the second parameter. But as I already stated, using /dev/urandom or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes doesn't improve anything.

Comment: Was a quick and dirty example, I've fixed it now.

Comment: "Note: due to the implementation of openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(), this function will be very slow." Heh. Turning openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() into an integer is actually faster than `mt_rand()`.